# Getting transparent image while trying to get screenshot in chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

I am trying to get screenshot in chrome in chrome extension.

```
function getSnapshotURI(dataURI, adDimensions) {
    if (!isSet(dataURI) || !isSet(adDimensions)) {
        return "";
    }
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        img = document.createElement('img'),
        context,
        left, top, width, height;

    img.onload = function () {
        left = adDimensions['left']*(img.width);
        width = adDimensions['width']*(img.width);
        top = adDimensions['top']*(img.height);
        height = adDimensions['height']*(img.height);
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(img, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
    };

    img.src = dataURI;

    console.log('data url canvas ..');
    console.log(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));

    return canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```

Here i am calling this function

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(details.windowId, {}, function (dataUri) {
            callback("Screenshot done");
            tab.setScreenshot(MnetUtil.getSnapshotURI(dataUri, details.adDimensions));
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.getTabId(), {src: 'bg', type: 'screenshotDone'});

        });
```

I am getting data uri and it is giving transparent image like this [image: scrrenshot image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you omit the usage of the  element the code should be working.  Tried it with just an '**img**' tag and the **dataURL** returned from the **chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()** method.

### background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (activeTab) {
    var visualizerPage = chrome.extension.getURL('/views/visualizer.html');

    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(undefined, undefined, function (dataUrl) {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: visualizerPage
        }, function (tab) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
                    'data': dataUrl
                });

            }, 1000);

        });
    });

});
```

### visualizer.html

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    var data = msg.data;

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = data;

    document.body.append(img);

});
```

Seems to me that the only reason you're using a '**canvas**' is to transform the image and convert it to *png* format.  [According to the API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab), you can specify the quality of the image directly through the **capture()** method.